# How to use top 1 from subquery in MariaDB?

Tags: mariadb, subquery, limit

Let's say I want to get the list of tickets, and for each ticket I want to find out the date of the latest post. In SQL Server I can do it this way:

```
select 
    Tickets.*
    (
        select top 1 [Date]
        from Posts 
        where TicketId = Tickets.Id
        order by [Date] desc
    ) as LatestPostDate
from Tickets
```

I realized that we can't use `top 1` in MariaDB. And as I searched, we should use `limit 1`. But this does not work:

```
select 
    Tickets.*
    (
        select `Date`
        from Posts 
        where TicketId = Tickets.Id
        order by `Date` desc
        limit 1
    ) as LatestPostDate
from Tickets
```

Answer (score 0):

You *can* use `LIMIT` in a sub-query. You are just missing a comma in your query:

```sql
select 
    Tickets.*,   <-- missing comma
    (
        select `Date`
        from Posts 
        where TicketId = Tickets.Id
        order by `Date` desc
        limit 1
    ) as LatestPostDate
from Tickets
```

In fact sub-queries should always have a `LIMIT 1` clause to make sure you always get only one row back.